# visual composer front editor not working

Tags: wordpress

Hi I'm using Word press visual composer .. the problem is that with some pages(not all pages) , the front editor is not working , it just keep loading endlessly ,at first it wasn't working with all pages .. but when I added a blank page , Front editor worked with the blank page and some other pages , so what to do to make visual composer front editor works with these pages?
I'm using word press the 7 theme.
this is my suffering:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be many reasons for this but the root is js error.

1. at first disable page "preloader" and try.
2. If not working try disabling other plugins for wordpress which may have js conflict.
3. The best way: Have a look on console log for js error in browser's developer tools and fix them.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply , and if you please tell me how to do that in details , as I'm a beginner and still learning how to walk.I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

i had problem with visual. In my case helped when i changed on classic mode and return to backend editor.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is mostly related to `composer-view.js`, I faced the same issue and it got resolved after following these links:
[visual-composer-templateget-is-not-a-functi](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/visual-composer-templateget-is-not-a-functi/) and [Visual Composer is not working](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/visual-composer-is-not-working/?replies=20)

You need to replace old code of `composer-view.js` as follow. (ps:- backup your old file before replacing this code.)
You can find this file at following location:

```
wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/backend
```

### Old Code

```
html2element: function ( html ) {
        var attributes = {},
            $template;
        if ( _.isString( html ) ) {
            this.template = _.template( html );
            $template = $( this.template( this.model.toJSON(), vc.templateOptions.default ).trim() );
        } else {
            this.template = html;
            $template = html;
        }
        _.each( $template.get( 0 ).attributes, function ( attr ) {
            attributes[ attr.name ] = attr.value;
        } );
        this.$el.attr( attributes ).html( $template.html() );
        this.setContent();
        this.renderContent();
    }
```

### Replace with new one as follows:

```
html2element:function (html) {
            var attributes = {},
                $template;
            if (_.isString(html)) {
                this.template = _.template(html);
            } else {
                try {
                    this.template = _.template(html());
                } catch (err) {
                    this.template = html;
                }
            }
            $template = $(this.template(this.model.toJSON()).trim());
            _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function (attr) {
                attributes[attr.name] = attr.value;
            });
            this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html());
            this.setContent();
            this.renderContent();
        }
```

then also replace the Render Function

### Old code

```
render: function () {
        var $shortcode_template_el = $( '#vc_shortcode-template-' + this.model.get( 'shortcode' ) );
        if ( $shortcode_template_el.is( 'script' ) ) {
            this.html2element( _.template( $shortcode_template_el.html(),
                this.model.toJSON(),
                vc.templateOptions.default ) );
        } else {
            var params = this.model.get( 'params' );
            $.ajax( {
                type: 'POST',
                url: window.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: 'wpb_get_element_backend_html',
                    data_element: this.model.get( 'shortcode' ),
                    data_width: _.isUndefined( params.width ) ? '1/1' : params.width,
                    _vcnonce: window.vcAdminNonce
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                context: this
            } ).done( function ( html ) {
                this.html2element( html );
            } );
        }
        this.model.view = this;
        this.$controls_buttons = this.$el.find( '.vc_controls > :first' );
        return this;
    }
```

### Replace with new code as follows:

```
 render: function () {
            var $shortcode_template_el = $( '#vc_shortcode-template-' + this.model.get( 'shortcode' ) );
            if ( $shortcode_template_el.is( 'script' ) ) {
                var newHtmlCode =  _.template( $shortcode_template_el.html(),
                                                this.model.toJSON(),
                                                vc.templateOptions.default );
                if(!_.isString(newHtmlCode)){
                    newHtmlCode = $shortcode_template_el.html();
                }
                this.html2element( newHtmlCode );
            } else {
                var params = this.model.get( 'params' );
                $.ajax( {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: window.ajaxurl,
                    data: {
                        action: 'wpb_get_element_backend_html',
                        data_element: this.model.get( 'shortcode' ),
                        data_width: _.isUndefined( params.width ) ? '1/1' : params.width,
                        _vcnonce: window.vcAdminNonce
                    },
                    dataType: 'html',
                    context: this
                } ).done( function ( html ) {
                    this.html2element( html );
                } );
            }
            this.model.view = this;
            this.$controls_buttons = this.$el.find( '.vc_controls > :first' );
            return this;
        }
```