# WordPress visual composer not loading

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, visual-composer

Hi I installed Rosie theme (Version: 1.4) and Installed visual composer (Version 4.4.2). Website was working very fine for more than a year without any issue, but now while editing the pages, the visual composer not loading... I have attached the image.

This is how it looks now

[image: This is how it looks now]

Comment: Please update your plugin and wordpress if you are not running in latest version. Visual composer 5.0 is released.

Comment: I answered this question at following link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44292095/1416821 It will work fine once you replace the old js code of visual composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this step

You can upgrade Visual Composer by performing following steps:

> 1. Please make sure main theme is activated while performing other steps
> 2. Go to Plugins page in your WordPress Dashboard, locate Visual Composer in the list, deactivate it and delete it
> 3. You will see message that required plugin is missing at the top of your WordPress Dashboard
> 4. Install the plugin and then activate it

Answer (score 1):

If you've got problems with Visual Composer you can almost always blame your PHP version or max characters:

1. Check compatibility of your Visual Composer with PHP version at your server using the link below:
   https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/preface/release-notes/
2. Check what PHP version you are using on the server: [To check your PHP version download plugin "PHP Info" ]
3. Check your Visual Composer version in your installed plugin list
4. If everything is compatible then do -> `set max_input_vars = 10000` in `php.ini` or ask your hosting provider to increase the limit. If not, then update your Visual Composer and increase the PHP version.
5. WordPress and theme update is also a good idea.